# Dynamic Form Fields not inserting all data into database

Tags: php, sql, forms, mysqli

I am trying to insert an array into a database via a dynamic form. The form will insert the first values from the form but not any more. tried a couple of methods and have hit a wall.

Here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
$con = new MySQLi(CONNECTION INFORMATION);
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}


foreach($_POST['room_types'] as $cnt => $room_types);
$room_type = implode(",", $room_types);

foreach($_POST['rooms'] as $cnt => $rooms);
$room = implode(",", $rooms);

foreach($_POST['users'] as $cnt => $users);
$user = implode(",", $users);
foreach($_POST['qty'] as $cnt => $qty);


$sql="INSERT INTO ConfigForm (HotelName,ADD1,ADD2, town, county, postcode, phone, fax, hotel_email, website_url, hotel_contact_name, accounts_contact_name, accounts_email, web_dev_company, web_dev_contact, web_dev_email, tarrif_selection, website_link, payment_select_box, barclays, barclays_store_id, barclays_username, barclays_password, worldpay, worldpay_username, worldpay_password, secpay_username, secpay_password, secpay_template, securetrading, securetrading_site_ref, securetrading_username, securetrading_password, sagepay, sagepay_account, sagepay_password, welcome_secure, welcome_secure_account, no_payment, paypal, paypal_account,roomnum,roomtype) 
VALUES
('$_POST[hotel_name]','$_POST[address_line1]','$_POST[address_line2]','$_POST[town]','$_POST[county]','$_POST[postcode]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[fax]','$_POST[hotel_email]','$_POST[website_url]','$_POST[hotel_contact_name]','$_POST[accounts_contact_name]','$_POST[accounts_email]','$_POST[web_dev_company]','$_POST[web_dev_contact]','$_POST[web_dev_email]','$_POST[tarru]','$_POST[website_link]','$_POST[payment_select_box]','$_POST[barclays]','$_POST[barclays_store_id]','$_POST[barclays_username]','$_POST[barclays_password]','$_POST[worldpay]','$_POST[worldpay_username]','$_POST[worldpay_password]','$_POST[secpay_username]','$_POST[secpay_password]','$_POST[secpay_template]','$_POST[securetrading]','$_POST[securetrading_site_ref]','$_POST[securetrading_username]','$_POST[securetrading_password]','$_POST[sagepay]','$_POST[sagepay_account]','$_POST[sagepay_password]','$_POST[welcome_secure]','$_POST[welcome_secure_account]','$_POST[no_payment]','$_POST[paypal]','$_POST[paypal_account]','$qty','".$_POST['name'][$cnt]."')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

echo "<h1>Form Submitted!<h1>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is a link to the form: http://apollowebtools.com/WAForm/config_form.html

Any help much appreciated, Thanks

Comment: did you get an error ?

Comment: no, the form runs through, gets to the form submitted.
all data apart from the 'added' values are inserted. Its like it doesnt know they are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**its obvious** What following line of codes does is

```
foreach($_POST['room_types'] as $cnt => $room_types);
```

iterate through the array and change the value of `$room_types` to each successive element of array. So after the `foreach` ends, `$room_types` is not an array but the last element of `$_POST['room_types']` array

you should go for:

```
$room = '';
foreach($_POST['room_types'] as $cnt => $room_types)
    $room .= ',' .$room_types;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is that you have not selected the database.

Add something like following:

```
<?php
      $con=mysqli_connect('host','user','password');
    
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo ("conection error : %s\n" . mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db("//database name", $con);

if (!$db_selected)
  {
  die ("Can\'t use this databse : " . mysqli_error());
  }
  
    ?>
```

more help can be found from this link: [mysqli_select_db](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp)

I'm not sure but hope this will work.

Comment: ('host', 'user', 'password', 'database') is what im using during the connection

Comment: @Jack_McG ok...so its not a problem...can you try to saperate them?

Comment: @Jack_McG try separating mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'pass') and then selecting databse...If it do not work, error should be something else.

Comment: @mebjas sorry but I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Check Your query, I think its not right.

Echo $sql and run this query in table manuaaly.

I can see $_POST[hotel_name], it must be $_POST['hotel_name']. You are not adding quotes.